# Using javascript in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

How can i change the 0 to be a variable that i can increase the value of when i loop the code

```
javaScript = "document.getElementsByTagName('cite')[0].click();"
browser.execute_script(javaScript)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python you could do this :

```
i = 0
javaScript = f"document.getElementsByTagName('cite')[{i}].click();"
browser.execute_script(javaScript)
```

I'm not sure how you want to `iterate`, but a standard way would be something like this :

```
i = 0
for x in range(5):
    javaScript = f"document.getElementsByTagName('cite')[{i}].click();"
    driver.execute_script(javaScript)
    i = i + 1
```